# Git not able to commit amend after cherryPick

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

The scenario is the following

> 1. Create new change commit and push (done OK) not merged yet lets call it **A**
> 2. After a while do git reset --hard origin then fetch and re-base against the master 
>      3.cherry pick the change **A**  and update two files
> 3. git add .
> 4. git Pull
> 5. git commit --amend
> 6. git push -f origin master

Now Im getting the following error:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: done
To ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I did a git pull before the commit and I get message that it up-to-date,any idea what I miss here? and how should I make it work?

I use intellij

Comment: Are you sure you’re using force push? Is the master branch protected on GitHub so that you cannot force-push to it? Why do you want to force push anyway? You already published the commit, so you shouldn’t amend it afterwards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `pull` and then `commit --amend` that messed things up.  Here's what you did, visually.  After you've pulled, `master` and `origin/master` are at the same commit.

```
A - B - C [master] [origin/master]
```

Then you did a `commit --amend`.  This takes the changes between B and C, plus your new edits, and creates a new commit D.  D's parent is B, so you've made a branch.

```
A - B - C [origin/master]
     \
      D [master]
```

`origin/master` and `master` have now diverged.  When you try to `push` git refuses because only fast forwards are allowed.

To fix this `git reset --soft origin/master`.  `--soft` will retain the work in D, but now your parent is C.  Then you can do a normal commit (not a commit amend).  This is the preferred option as it allows you to `push` normally and won't mess up anyone else's work.

```
         [origin/master]
A - B - C - E [master]
     \
      D
```

(D will be garbage collected).

Alternatively you can `git push --force`.  This tells git that D is the new tip of `master` now and to throw out C.  Forcing a push is very unfriendly to other developers whose work based on C will now be invalid.  They'll get errors trying to `pull` and will have to do work to fix it up and it's a big mess.

---

Rule of thumb is once you've pushed a change, *don't rebase it*.  `git commit --amend` counts as rebasing.

And don't habitually force push.

Comment: In the last note, you're saying that force-pushing would be an alternative approach here that would work. However, Mark is using `git push -f` in step 6, but still failing. I suspect he is not actually allowed to force-push to `origin/master`. There might be a good reason for that, too.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me when should I do the soft assume I do all the steps again ?

Comment: @Mark It's hard for me to know exactly what's wrong, but somewhere along the line your `master` has diverged from `origin/master`. At this point your best bet is to look at the repository with a visualizer like [GitX](https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/) or [gitk](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitk) and find where it diverged. Either `merge` your master with `origin/master` or `rebase` your `master` onto `origin/master` or any number of other ways. If you post a screenshot of your repo visualization that might help.